# Powering DC Motor with Spark Core and arduino motor shield R3

Tags: arduino, sparkcore

I am trying to run a motor shield without the shield shield with a spark core. I got an Arduino to run the motor shield using this code :

```
int a = 12;
int abrake = 9;
int aspeed = 3;

void setup()
{
  // Initialize D0 pin as output
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(abrake, OUTPUT);
}

// This routine loops forever
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(abrake, LOW);
  analogWrite(aspeed, 225);
}
```

I then wiped the arduino so it wasn't running any code but was powering the shield.
Then I tried to use a spark core to control the motor shield.

I hooked

D0 -> 12

D1 -> 9

D0 -> 3

And used this code :

```
int a = D0;
int abrake = D1;
int aspeed = D2;

void setup()
{
  // Initialize D0 pin as output
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(abrake, OUTPUT);
}

// This routine loops forever
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(abrake, LOW);
  analogWrite(aspeed, 225);
}
```

My wiring :

[image: Wiring]
[image: More wiring]

Is this way even possible?
Am i doing something wrong? 
Is there an easier solution?

Comment: Does the Spark share a common ground with the Arduino (motor shield power source)? You need that.

Comment: same result. Should this theoretically work?

Comment: Here's a video showing the spark core connected to a motor shield directly. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=629VVNp0Z5Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnalogWrite to a Digital Pin will only work on D0 and D1 since they have PWM capabilities only.  I am guessing it is just ignoring the analog write.  Get out the old meter and check.

Here is a link to their super helpful docs.

http://docs.spark.io/hardware/#spark-core-datasheet-pins-and-i-o